# How does the dual annealing algorithm work?

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize, simulated-annealing

I'm using the scipy dual annealing algorithm to minimize a function and I am thinking about how this algorithm actually works in comparison to standard or generalized simulated annealing. I do not understand the maxiter parameter because the function evaluations are always way higher than the amount of iterations.
If anyone knows the pseudocode I would much appreciate it.

I did look up the mentioned papers on the scipy page but these weren't helpful regarding my question.

Comment: The documentation has a link to the source code: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.11.1/scipy/optimize/_dual_annealing.py#L440-L716

Comment: If maxiter was a limit on function evaluations it would be named `maxfun` instead (and in fact dual_annealing does support `maxfun`.)

Comment: @jared Thank you very much. How could I miss that...

Comment: @hobbs Yes I am very aware of that, that is actually my question. Why is the maxfun higher than maxiter? As far as I know in standard simulated annealing there is no distinction between these two.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With my Colleague Yang, we wrote it. Maxiter is the maximum number of the global iterations (which includes the global search process which embeds local searches). This is not the same thing as the maximum number of objective function calls. If you want to limit the number of objective function calls, use maxfun. If you want to make sure it runs longer than the default maximum number of iteration (which is by default 500 and automatically adapted to the parameters dimension space), then use maxiter. I hope this helps.
Sylvain

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).